# How do I talk to Firebug from a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, web-worker

My web workers are becoming increasingly complicated and I'm sorely missing Firebug access while working with them. This:

```
console.log("test");
```

Does not produce anything from a web worker. I've also tried the following:

```
dump("test");
```

And that doesn't produce any output either.

Firefox version:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5
```

Firebug version 1.4X.5

Comment: I'm asking how to talk to Firebug from a web worker. I've listed two ways I've tried to do so. I've mentioned I'm trying to debug a web worker. I've written my goal in the title. What's unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't print to console directly. You have to send messages from worker threads to the main window and then print to console from there. See this article for details: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/25/web-workers-errors-and-debugging/.